# Trying to format data retrieved from sqlite3 database by removing certain strings. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, replace, sqlite

```
c.execute("SELECT Date, BehaviourType, BehaviourDescription "+
          "FROM Student "+
          "WHERE Forename = :forename "+
            "AND Surname = surname "+
            "AND YearGroup = :yeargroup "+
            "AND FormNumber = :formnumber "+
            "AND Date BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate",
          {"forename": forename,
           "surname": surname,
           "yeargroup": yeargroup,
           "formnumber": formnumber,
           "startdate": startdate,
           "enddate": enddate})

        studentRequest = c.fetchall()
        record = str(studentRequest)

    #write to file
        f = open('Student Report', 'w')
        f.write('Name: ' + name)
        f.write(' Form Number: ' + (yeargroup +'/'+ formnumber))
        for records in record:
            record.replace("u'", " ")
            record.replace("'", " ")
            record.replace("(", " ")
            record.replace(")", " ")
            f.write(str(records))
        f.close()
```

The replace() methods do not seem to be working but the program is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two problems here:**

1. Inside the `for` loop, you are applying the `replace` function on `record` instead of `records`.
2. The `replace` function returns a new string, which you are "throwing away" every time you call it.

The solution to both, is changing `record.replace(...)` to `records = records.replace(...)`.

BTW, for better readability, I would rename `record` to `records` and vice-versa...

**Update:**

You have a more basic problem, I believe, with `record = str(studentRequest)`.

Here is how you should probably do it:

```
studentRequests = c.fetchall()

for studentRequest in studentRequests:
    record = str(studentRequest)
    record = record.replace("u'"," ")
    record = record.replace("'" ," ")
    record = record.replace("(" ," ")
    record = record.replace(")" ," ")
    f.write(record+"\n") # or "\r\n" if your program is running on Unix
```

Comment: Thank you, silly mistake from me. I have now solved this. However, how can i write things to a certain line in the text file as it is currently all printing on the same line?

Comment: I have tried that but am not having any luck with it. It seems to print not work so I altered the code a little. However when i try with this new code, it likes to save "/r/n" to the file.                f = open('Student Report', 'w')
   f.write('Name: ' + name)
   f.write(' Form Number: ' + (yeargroup +'/'+ formnumber))
   #for records in record:
   records = records.replace("u'", " ")
   records = records.replace("'", " ")
   records = records.replace("(", " ")
   records = records.replace(")", " ")

   for rds in records:
    f.write(rds+"/r/n")
   f.close()

Comment: OK, I think I understand your basic problem; please see revised answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Would it be possible to implement recursion here seeing as "record" is being used many times? I am hoping to use recursion somewhere

Comment: Why do you need to use recursion for? It doesn't seem appropriate here in any way...

Comment: It is required of me to implement recursion so if it is possible, including it would of be benefit to me. Your help so far has been great though, I am quite new to Python.